# Need help making team LINEUP by dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Imagine you are a football team-coach. There are 11 players and 11 different positions in the field in which players play. Each player is capable of playing at all 11 different positions with a certain rating at the specified position.

You being the coach of the team have to decide the strongest possible LINEUP for the team (consisting of all 11 players) such that overall rating (i.e, sum of ratings) is maximized.
No two players can play at the same position.

As an example, consider a smaller LINEUP problem in which only 3 players play a certain game.

```
3 2 1
4 1 5
6 7 3
```

Player 1 can play at position 1 with rating 3, at position 2 with rating 2 and at position 3 with rating 1. Similarly for all the players the ith column represents their rating at ith position. The best LINEUP will be when player 1 plays at position 1, player 2 at position 3 and player 3 at position 2, resulting in maximum rating = 15 (3 + 5 + 7).

So, how can this problem be solved by Dynamic Programming? I have read on forums someone solving this problem by DP but I am unable to figure out how the problem possesses Optimal Substructure. So please help me figure out that....

Plz also mention that is it possible or not to solve the problem by DP

And please edit the title appropriately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have an assignment problem here, which can be solved by the [Hungarian Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

And if you really want to have a DP solution, here is one idea. Why not have a `F[i,j]`, `i=0..11`, `j = 0..2^11-1`. `i` - is the number of players you are allowed to select from and `j` - is a bitmask representing the field positions that are covered and `F` is the maximum "team value" you can get. For `i = 1`, for example, only those values of `j` whose binary representation contains at most one set bit are "valid". Obviously you cannot conver more than one position with just one player.

```
// initialize the F[][] array with -infinity
F[0][0] = 0;

for(i = 1; i <= 11; ++1)
{
  for(j = 0; j < 2^11; ++j)
    for(k = 0; k < 11; ++k )
    if( (j & (1 << k)) == 0 ) // k-th position is not occupied?
      F[i][j | (1 << k)] = max( F[i][j | (1 << k)], F[i-1][j] + <value of payer i playing at position k> );
}

ANSWER = F[11][2^11-1]
```

This obviously can be optimized: for `F[i]` we are only interested in bitmasks containing exactly `i` set bits.

There was a name for the technique of turning a combinatorial problem into a DP problem by representing the possible states with a bitmap, but I don't remember it. The proper solution for this is still Hungarian method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Learned something new & what about optimal substructure

Comment: @khirod, I am not sure what you mean by optimal substructure but I outlined a "cheat-DP" solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: You can also change the first dimension to just 2 and use `F[i & 1]` or `F[1 - (i & 1)]` to access it instead of `F[i]` or `F[i - 1]` respectively, since you only ever need the previous or current array.  In fact you can get rid of this dimension entirely if you iterate j *down* from 2^11 to 0 and consider how to form the lineup j by adding player i to each position r such that `r | (1 << k) == j`.  This is because the solutions to these subproblems will not yet have been processed for this value of i, since they are all missing 1 bit that is in j and are therefore numerically smaller :)

Comment: Furthermore, all sub-lineups `r` can be found in O(number_of_1_bits_in_j) by repeatedly subtracting off the lowest 1-bit in j, using the trick `j & -j` to find this lowest 1-bit :) This would mean replacing the `k` loop with a loop that iterated through just these bits.

Comment: Now it looks like a breadth-first search. For every bitmask we can obtain all other bitmasks that we get by setting one new bit: we invert the bitmask and apply the `j & -j` trick. Naturally, the bitmasks discovered from bitmask 0 will be those containing one bit set, the next "wave" of bitmasks will contain 2 bits etc... But still the Hungarian method should be applied here. 8 - )

Comment: You're right about the Hungarian method! Indeed you can continue using your strategy of considering all the lineups that can be generated by adding player i to the current (jth) partial solution (instead of my approach of considering all the ways that the jth partial solution could be formed by adding player i to each lineup having i-1 players), but you need to loop j *downwards*, otherwise you will "contaminate" the scores of lineups you haven't considered yet :) (Of course this is only a problem if you try to get rid of 1 array dimension as I suggested.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I am thinking of eliminating the loop over j. It will be like Dijkstra algorithm. We will need an array F[0 .. 2^11-1], a bit-vector Visited[0..2^11-1] and two lists of bitmasks: lCur and lNext. Initially lCur={00000000000}, lNext={}. then `for (i=0;i<11;++i) { for(<bitmap B in lCur>) { for (<bits X not set in B>) { F[B&X]=max(F[B&X],F[B]+...); if(!Visited[B&X]) {lNext += B&X; Visited[B&X]=true;} } } lCur=lNext; lNext = {}; }` Hope this comes out readable...

Comment: Ah, thanks. Provided that you keep `lCur` and `lNext` separate (as your code indicates) you should have no problems. It's quite similar to my first solution where the first array dimension is reduced to 2, but more efficient because you don't waste time iterating over lineups with not enough people.

Answer (score 0):

it's a matching problem.
u can use KM algorithm to solve that [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KM_algorithm)
and Hungarian Method which Alex mentioned is a special case of KM.
for DP method, Ales gave the right answer. since the number of players is not big, a bit manipulation method can be used here